# Get real text with beautifulSoup after unwrap()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need your help : I have `<p>` tag with many other tags in like in the example below :

```
<p>I <strong>AM</strong> a <i>text</i>.</p>
```

I would like to get only "I am a text" so I unwrap() the tags `strong` and `i`
with the code below :

```
for elem in soup.find_all(['strong', 'i']):
    elem.unwrap()
```

Next, if i print the `soup.p` all is right, but if i don't know the name of the tag where my string is, problems start !

The code below should be more clear :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<html>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <p>I <strong>AM</strong> a <i>text</i>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for elem in soup.find_all(['strong', 'i']):
    elem.unwrap()

print soup.p 
# output :
# <p>I AM a text.</p>

for s in soup.stripped_strings:
    print s
# output 

'''
I
AM
a
text
.
'''
```

Why does BeautifulSoup separate all my strings while I concatenate it with my unwrap() before ?

Comment: You should unrwap the `p`...

Comment: I precise that I need to keep the parent (in my case, the P) in my soup because i need to know the tags where the texts that I extract are.

Answer (score 6):

If you **`.unwrap()`** the tag, you **remove the tag, and put the content in the parent tag**. But the **text is not merged**, as a result, you obtain a **list of `NavigableString`s** (a subclass of `str`):

```
>>> [(c,type(c)) for c in soup.p.children]
[('I ', <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>), ('AM', <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>), (' a ', <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>), ('text', <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>), ('.', <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>)]
```

Each of these elements thus is a *separated* text element. So although you removed the tag itself, and injected the text, these strings are not concatenated. This seems logical, since the elements on the left and the right *could* still be tags: by unwrapping `<strong>` you have not unwrapped `<i>` at the same time.

You can however use `.text`, to obtain the full text:

```
>>> soup.p.get_text()
'I AM a text.'
```

Or you can decide to `join` the elements together:

```
>>> ''.join(soup.p.strings)
'I AM a text.'
```

Comment: Pretty clear ! Thank you. I thought it would merge it automatically.. no way to join it on the go ? In my example I know that I need to merge text of a `p` but in the real life, I do not know what my parent tags are :(

Comment: The Beautiful Soup 4 docs only mention [.get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) - I wouldn't recommend using `.text` (or `.string`, which also exists for some reason).

Comment: @Quentin: not that I know of. In that sense `.get_text()` will probably be the best: it leaves the tree intact and furtermore will fetch the text recursively.

Comment: @Quentin You can sort of join it "on the go" by checking for `NavigableString`s in the beginning and end of and before and after the unwrapped element, and replacing them with a joined `NavigableString` as fitting. Nothing built into the API, though.

Answer (score 3):

Α kinda hacky (yet easy) way I found to solve this is to convert the "clean" soup into a string and then parse it again.

So, in your code

```
for elem in soup.find_all(['strong', 'i']):
    elem.unwrap()

string_soup = str(soup)

new_soup = BeautifulSoup(string_soup, 'lxml')

for s in new_soup .stripped_strings:
    print s
```

should give the desirable output